# What PC Van stands for?

Tags: renault, van, conversion

I found [a promo video](https://youtu.be/cdxx9mtxIDE?t=113) of Renault Tech company which does PC Van conversions.

[image: PC Van Conversion]

Now I am wondering what PC Van stands for and what is a purpose of it? Wouldn't it be easier to buy MPV instead?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PC stands for "Passenger Car(s)" ... in this case, Renault Tech is taking a Passenger Car
and doing a conversion on it to what you're seeing in the video. [Here is some Renault literature](https://group.renault.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/vgb-dr-2017-mise-en-ligne.pdf) (pg 24) on the subject. From this same document on page 23, they state they are also doing LCV (Light Commercial Vehicles) and EV (Electric Vehicles), which also shows up in other places.